# Using PHP to redirect when SQL query comes up empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using this PHP script to return search input values with corresponding URL values on a MySQL database/table. The idea is to append them to a redirect to automatically jump to that page.

```
<?php
$searchResults = $_POST['search'];
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'admin';
$dbpass = 'pwd';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = "SELECT url
    FROM Table_1
    WHERE input = '" .$searchResults."'";

mysql_select_db('database_1');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $redirect = $row['url'];
    header('Location:'.$redirect);  
}
```

To catch any input that does not match a value on Table_1 added this If statement.  It will take any non relevant or misspelled inputs and redirect them to xyz.html

```
if (mysql_num_rows($retval) < 1)  {

header('Location: xyz.html');

}
```

**Is this incorrect?**  It seems to be working but I assume there must be a cleaner way of doing this/ it may be **bad practice.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are expecting only one result from the query then it would work.
But if there are multiple rows then the last row would be loaded . It would be inefficient then.
You could also directly do this:

```
if($retval)
{ .$row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC);
 header('Location:'.$row);
}
else 
header('Location:xyz.html');
```

You wouldn't need to use the while loop if you are expecting only one row.

Comment: He is firstly asking if its Correct or Wrong approach. And by the way its wrong approach.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  The query will only ever return 1 value.  In your response is $result a new variable?

Comment: To "optimise" further you could add LIMIT 1 to the SQL query

Answer (score 2):

The way you use is wrong, it may cause lots of headache.

2 ways :

```
 1.If result is x then redirect to page A.

 2.If result is x then load view just similar like page A with same header ,footer.
```

So , as per 2nd way ,when the query is empty , Load specific view which you want.

For your example , suppose you visit a Shopping cart Site, you clicked on Shoes category , if there is no shoes, the page shows message `Sorry stock is empty, no shoes`, it does not redirect you to any page if stock if empty.

Comment: Hey thanks for responding, should i just include the IF statement after the WHILE statement like i have it, or can i get rid of the WHILE statement?